# Safari Border Radius clipping issue

Tags: html, css, safari

I know similar questions to this have been asked, but they all point to background-clip which isn't working.

The top is Safari, the bottom is everybody else: http://tinypic.com/r/2ng616v/5

How my HTML is structured:

```
<div class="parent" style="border:1px solid gray;border-radius:5px">
        <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

What's the best way to fix Safari with this setup?

Comment: First step is to post your html and css and the second is to make jsfiddle, then we will see.

Comment: What version(s) of Safari is this happening with? It was a known issue with older versions (and with older versions of other browsers too) but I thought it was fixed by now.

Comment: @Spudley Safari 5.1.7 Windows.

Comment: @VladislavStanic http://jsfiddle.net/QbtuQ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution? I added left: 0; and decreased width of .child. If you need to change its size just change width instead of left position.

```
.parent {
width:200px;
height:30px;
border-radius:15px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
}
.child {
width:70px;
height:30px;
border-radius:15px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
background:red;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QbtuQ/3/)

Comment: This almost works, but as you can see (a little better) from this ginormous version, http://jsfiddle.net/QbtuQ/4/ there's that pixel or so of "white" space that doesn't quite get filled. The effect is even worse when you're dealing with a 10px height. Any ideas on fixing that?

Comment: Look what happens when I remove border and set background on parent. http://jsfiddle.net/QbtuQ/5/  If you want to fill that 1px of white space and to still have border, you just have to do .child {border-radius: 49px;}. It seems fine to me now. http://jsfiddle.net/QbtuQ/6/

Comment: That almost works, but as you can see with a larger border, not quite: http://jsfiddle.net/QbtuQ/7/ So I rectified that with a slightly different solution: http://jsfiddle.net/QbtuQ/8/ Seems to work in Safari and IE okay. The rest are probably fine as well.

Comment: Seems fine. You only have to decrease child's border-radius for the width of parent's border. Was glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this…

```
background-clip: padding-box;  
-moz-background-clip: padding;  
-webkit-background-clip: padding;
```

Read more here: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/

Comment: From original post: "but they all point to background-clip which isn't working."